# Problems publishing site to localhost on windows 2008 rs server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, windows-server-2008-r2

I must preface this post by saying that I am not an experienced developer, I am in the process of learning through trial and error and a lot of google searches so detailed (step-by-step) feedback would be greatly appreciated.  I created a website, which does not use a database,  using visual studio 2015 and I am attempting to host it locally on a Windows 2008 R2 server.

I installed IIS and loaded the asp.net v4.0 framework.  The site works fine, produces no errors when I test it and works after being published only if the visual studio is still running.

However, when I close the Visual studio and open my browser window to http://localhost:50044 (which is the URL listed in properties menu in VS),  I also tried using port :80 and nothing.  When trying to add Web Site via the IIS management utility I receive the following authentication error: ”Cannot verify access path (C:\Inetpub\wwwroot).”

I checked the permissions and windows authentication is enabled with read access, and all other permissions seem to be correct.  I am at a loss, I'm sure it is probably something simple that I am missing due to my lack of knowledge and experience.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sounds like you are running on IIS express which in your case stops running when you close visual studio. Normal process is create a new website in IIS and point to the folder where your web.config is. You can then hack your host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) so DNS works. Add an entry like "127.0.0.1 mytestwebsite.com". I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Jeremy!  I will give it a shot.  I am pretty green when it comes to working with IIS and server 2008 so please forgive my ignorance.  How do I hack the host file?  And when adding the entry should I use my IP and do I have to use the same naming convention as the root folder?  Thanks again!  Dan

Comment: I forgot to add that this site is an intranet, therefore does not have a www address.

Comment: Ok, I followed your suggestions and still hit a wall.  I basically started from scratch, created the site in iis, changed the host file, and published it to file system and web deploy.  I turned the firewall off added a new user role IIS_computername and gave it read access

Comment: Gave read access to all other users including anonymous and still can't access the site.  I also made sure that all of my folders were shared, even the C:. I checked the path in iis, and made sure the application host config file points at my directory.   I am losing my marbles here.

Comment: How are you handling DNS for the intranet? Maybe add some screen shots of your IIS bindings and App pool if you need further assistance. Anyway glad I could help

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I'll take some screen shots tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out part of what was happening.   I didn't realize that visual studio has built in IIS and was using that by default.

I ran VS as an admin, created a new project, then attempted to create a virtual directory thru VS under the project/properties/web tab.  I selected local IIS and entered http://localhost/boc and it returns an error: unable to create vd.  Web server http://localhost... Could not be found.

I then went in to the IIS manager and set up a virtual directory with no issues.  However, when I attempt to reference it thru VS I again receive an error message.

Any ideas?

Comment: "when I attempt to reference it thru VS I again receive an error message" do you mean when you try and attach to w3wp for debugging? what is the error message?